# Alternative metaphor for emphasizing difficult process

Tags: expressions, phrase-requests, metaphors

I am trying to describe the development process of some of my work for conference proceedings. We took laboratory research and adapted it for classroom experiences. A metaphor that came to mind was "out of the frying pan and into the fire" however this seems to emphasize the difficult nature of the starting and ending places rather than difficulty of the process between them. What alternative expressions would emphasize the difficulty of the process between to places?

Comment: What about "trying times"?  E.g: "We went through trying times while implementing the process from point A to point B"...

Comment: Another suggestion: "break the back of the beast" - If someone breaks the back of the beast, they succeed in overcoming a major difficulty. E.g: "After months of effort, we finally broke the back of the beast and got the problem solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a ***tough slog***, or a ***long, tough slog*** or, to be more positive, a **tough slog, but rewarding**

**slog**, from [The Free Dictionary](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/slog) means:

> v.intr.
>   1.  To walk or progress with a slow heavy pace; plod: slog across the swamp; slogged through both volumes.
>
> 2. To work diligently for long hours: slogged away at Latin.
>
> v.tr.
>   1.  To make (one's way) with a slow heavy pace against resistance.
>
> 2. To strike with heavy blows.
>
> n.
>   1.  A long exhausting march or hike: a slog through miles of jungle.
>
> 2. A long session of hard work: an 18-hour slog in the hay fields

We see that a **slog** is by definition difficult and long. A **tough slog** adds emphasis to the difficulty and a **long, tough slog** adds emphasis to the prolonged nature of the slog.

Examples of **tough slog** and **long, tough slog**

From [The Hill](http://thehill.com/blogs/ballot-box/presidential-races/275633-why-ted-cruz-faces-tough-slog-in-winning-over-new-york)

> Why Ted Cruz faces tough slog in winning over New York

From [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/blogs/plum-line/wp/2016/03/15/the-democratic-primary-is-going-to-be-a-long-tough-slog-and-thats-just-fine/?utm_term=.5825f7b2d9f0)

> The Democratic primary is going to be a long, tough slog. And that’s
>   just fine.

Finally, I think you need to say that the experience was positive.  Thus, my suggestion is **a tough slog, but rewarding**, or **a tough slog, but worth it**.